# Show single value of one column for multiple rows of other columns

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have a SQL query which displays my data results like this.

***date            emp_id     emp_name     spent_hours***

19-08-2013         1024       jack         10

19-08-2013         1024       jack         11

19-08-2013         1024       jack         09

19-08-2013         1024       jack         08

19-08-2013         1024       jack         11

but, I would like to display as below.

***date            emp_id     emp_name     spent_hours***

19-08-2013         1024       jack         10

```
                  11

                  09

                  08

                  11
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Do you generate the output with PHP? (according to your mysqli-tag I guess it does). This can best be done at the PHP-side, otherwise you are making your SQL-query way to complex.

Comment: Agreed - this is a _display_ issue.  Don't do display tasks in the db layer.

Comment: SQL queries don't "display" anything. Client software executing those queries and processing their results does.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the presentation layer is the best place to do the type of output shaping you're looking to do, but that being said, you can put the output from the base query into a temporary table and manipulate it to your heart's content.

Here's an example that uses a temporary table:

[SQL Fiddle, temporary table](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc433/1/0)

The main value of a temporary table is that it can use auto_increment to preserve the order of the base query.  Another option is to place the base query into derived tables.  In the example, you would need to replace the query

```
SELECT *, @row_num_[xy] := @row_num_[xy]+1 as row_num
FROM Output
ORDER BY row_id
```

with the base query, leaving the row_num generation intact.

[SQL Fiddle, derived table](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4708/2/2)

Comment: Thank you Jim. Is there any way to do this without creating temporary   table. Please advise on this...

Comment: I'm glad I could help Prakki.  Good luck!